# AllowUserToResizeColumns and AllowUserToResizeRows of the datagridview doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I want to allow user from resizing columns and prevent hom from resizing rows. I am setting the properties in design and also at runtime but it doesn't affect the datagridview.
The opposite happens, the rows can be resized and the columns not.
I tried to reverse the properties values but same result.

```
    private void SetupAlternatesDataGridView()
    {
        var recordstateColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        recordstateColumn.Name = Glossary.RecordState;
        recordstateColumn.HeaderText = Glossary.RecordStateTitle;

        var alternateStatusColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        alternateStatusColumn.Name = Glossary.AliasAlternateStatus;
        alternateStatusColumn.HeaderText = Glossary.AlternateStatusTitle;

        var alternateNumberColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        alternateNumberColumn.Name = Glossary.AliasAlternateNumber;
        alternateNumberColumn.HeaderText = Glossary.AlternateNumberTitle;

        AlternateDGV.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
        AlternateDGV.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;

        //TODO: For test only, remove it
        AlternateDGV.Columns.AddRange(recordstateColumn, alternateStatusColumn, alternateNumberColumn);
        AlternateDGV.Rows.Add("added", "A", "POS-100");
    }
```

How to make those properties work?

Comment: Did you try allowing them both on design side and writing allow lines to the end of function?

Comment: Just tried, same issue

Answer (score 2):

Just play with all the properties and found that AutoSizeColumnsMode must be set to None in order to AllowUserToResizeColumns and AllowUserToResizeRows to work.

```
AutoSizeColumnsMode = None
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't work because I had this line:

```
Grid.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

In other words, if you ask one column to fill all available space, the user won't be able to resize it (at least on Windows 10).
But if your entire grid is set to "Fill", like this:

```
Grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode =  DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

then resizing will be allowed.